# Tool or code to take a graphQL schema + set of operations and produce a schema subset?

Tags: graphql

Let's say I've got the following:

- A giant GraphQL schema for some service (in .graphql or introspection json format)
- A set of operations that my code wants to perform against that query.

I'd really like to generate a "subset schema": just the pieces (types/enums/etc) of that big schema that my service actually uses. Is there a tool or a piece of code that can do this today easily?

The reason I want this is that we want to mock graphql services to write isolated tests of particular microservices, and we want to mock out just the bits we actually use, and keep track of any changes in our schema usage over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a solution to this, so eventually I wrote one!

https://github.com/xometry/graphql-code-generator-subset-plugin - this tool is a plugin to the graphql-code-generator tool which will product a schema subset.